# SwiftUI: @ObservedObject vs @StateObject child view performance?

Tags: swiftui

I have the following view:

```
struct Menu: View {

    let sctions:[TestSection] = [

        TestSection(id: 0, name: "One", items: [
            ListItem(id: 0, name: "1"),
            ListItem(id: 1, name: "2"),
            ListItem(id: 2, name: "3"),
            ListItem(id: 3, name: "4")
        ]),

        TestSection(id: 1, name: "Two", items: [
            ListItem(id: 4, name: "4"),
            ListItem(id: 5, name: "5"),
            ListItem(id: 6, name: "6"),
            ListItem(id: 7, name: "7")
        ]),

        TestSection(id: 2, name: "Three", items: [
            ListItem(id: 8, name: "8"),
            ListItem(id: 9, name: "9"),
        ])
    ]

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(sctions) { section in

                    Section(header: Text(section.name)) {

                        ForEach(section.items) { item in
                            TestCell(item: item)
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .navigationBarTitle("Title")
        }
    }

}






struct TestCell: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var model:ItemModel
    
    let item:ListItem
    
    init(item:ListItem) {
        self.item = item
        self.model = ItemModel(itemId:item.id)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("item: \(item.name)")
        
        
    }
    
}


class ItemModel:ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var someProperty:Int
    
    let itemId:Int
    
    init(itemId:Int) {
        self.itemId = itemId
        self.someProperty = 0
    }
    
}
```

I am trying to decide how to handle child views in SwiftUI from a model layer point of view.

One option is `@ObservedObject` in the child view. The parent created the model and sets it on the child or the parent passes in a property on the child that then allows the child to init the model in its initializer:

```
init(item:ListItem) {
    self.item = item
    self.model = ItemModel(itemId:item.id). // <<---- HERE
}
```

Then looking at this, I wonder if this is less performant than using a `@StateObject` in the child view that would manage its model's lifecycle.

So then I tried this:

```
struct TestCell: View {

    @StateObject var model = ItemModel() // <<-- error "Missing argument for parameter 'itemId' in call"

    let item:ListItem

    var body: some View {

        Text("item: \(item.name)")


    }

}
```

Which, obviously shows the error:

[image]

I am not sure how to initialize `ItemModel` in `TestCell` when using the `@StateObject` approach.

The question I have is:

in this type of scenario, **where I want each cell to have its own model** (to handle model related logic like making network calls, updating model layer etc...) should I be creating the model as I instantiate the cell within the parent during cell creation, and setting it on the cell (`@ObservedObject`)?

Or should a cell use `@StateObject` for its model, and if so, how would I have the model initialize itself properly when it needs parameters, like `let itemId:Int` for example?

Answer (score 0):

Your first option is not recommended because

```
init(item:ListItem) {
    self.item = item
    self.model = ItemModel(itemId:item.id). // <<---- HERE
}
```

> it’s unsafe to create an observed object inside a view

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

You will find many questions in SO that talk about `View`s being unreliable. You'll also find the ones that tell people to do it this way but you will see issues with it.

If you use  `@StateObject var model: ItemModel = ItemModel()` which is the only exception according to Apple for creating an  `ObservableObject` In a  `View`

And switch

```
let itemId:Int
```

in your `ItemModel` to

```
var itemId:Int = 0
```

Then in `TestCell` add to the outermost `View`

```
.onAppear(){
    model.itemId = item.id
}
```

Or depending on your ParentView and its ViewModel you can create the `ObservableObject`s in the `class` ViewModel and pass it as a parameter for

```
@ObservedObject private var model:ItemModel
```

The important thing is that the workaround takes into consideration that an `ObservableObject` should not be created in a `View` with the exception of  `@StateObject`. SwiftUI reserves the right to re-create any `View` whenever it decides that it is necessary.

Comment: So, @StateObject is not to be considered at all as an option to drive the cell?

Comment: No, StateObject is the best option. I somehow jumped over that when I was offering the option. StateObject is the only save way to initialize an ObservableObject in a View.

Comment: Ok, so if I initialize the object in the view then StateObject is the preferred way. If I want to pass it down from the parent view then ObservedObject is the way to go?

Comment: It depends I prefer EnvironmentObject for most cases but others prefer ObservedObject.